# What does this pronoun refer to?

Tags: pronouns

May I ask whether the bolded pronoun **they** refer to *arts subjects* or *the students*

> In a speech yesterday, the Education Minister advised students to
> avoid arts subjects and choose science or maths if they want to
> improve their job prospects. In the past, he said, arts subjects like
> languages and history were chosen by students who didn't have a clear
> idea of what they wanted to do in the future. He explained that this
> was because of a feeling that **they** involved skills that were
> useful for many different jobs, but he questioned whether this was
> still true:'Nowadays, we...

Answer (score 5):

*They* refers to the art subjects. People don't <strike>involve</strike> skills, they [have/possess/acquire/learn](https://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=skill) them.